# Adding server to hosts-file speeds up its response

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a server, that I work with via SSH. It took quite a lot time (a few seconds) to request the password before I've added it to my `/etc/hosts` file, but after I've done that there is no pause between SSH command and password request.  I'm curious, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNS lookup is what is taking time.

Adding

```
UseDNS no
```

To your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will achieve the same thing

Comment: Probably - another likely candidate is an ident lookup. Both would be evident from monitoring the outgoing traffic on the server.